# NextJs App router i18n - change folder (route) names based on language

Tags: next.js, internationalization, app-router

I'm trying to setup internationalization for my nextjs app. I see in the recommended packages listed here https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization the way to translate a page is to add a language in the url like that

https://example.com/ - this is home for English let's say
https://example.com/pl - this is a home page for polish language for example

this is all clear and very well documented. What I cannot find is how I can translate a routes in app router that are folders in my application

e.g.

in my app folder I have

**/app/evens/page.tsx** and this translate to route **https://example.com/events** or **https://example.com/pl/events** if I use recommended approach

It is not what I would like to get at the end. I would like to translate a full route and end up with English route **https://example.com/events** after translation to polish to be **https://example.com/pl/zawody** (zawody is polish word for events)

has anyone done something similar in nextjs 13/14 with app router ? Thank you in advance!